# Import arbitrary XML to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

Is that possible to parse and import an **arbitrary** XML file to SQL Server tables using C#?

The XML file can be highly hierarchical.

I have 1 Gb XML-file, I do not know anything about it.

How can I determine what tables it contains, create them at SQL Server and bulk load the data to SQL Server?

Is that possible?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking here. You are using "shred", and "parse". Where do you want to do this - on the client or on SQL Server? Do you mean _pass_ XML to SQL Server?

Comment: Sorry for my terminology, English is not my native language :)

Comment: Please edit and improve the question then. I don't know what "shred" means at all in this context, and "parse" has a very specific meaning. Please explain what you want to do with the information as well.

Comment: i.e. I have 1 Gb XML-file, I do not know nothing about it. How can I determine tables in it, create them at SQL Server and bulk load data to SQL Server? Is that possible?

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add the details in your last comment to it.

Answer (score 1):

No.

XML and SQL are very, very different things.  It is possible to take SQL data an save it into XML, and such SQL-like XML can be converted back to an SQL database, but arbitrary XML that did not originate in an SQL-like system is not likely to be easily convertible to an SQL database schema in any meaningful way.

You could work out an SQL schema that represents generic XML in a key-value type design but it would not be an SQL schema in the traditional meaning of the word.